# Current and previous days date diff in days with some condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have the first three fields of the following table. I want to compute the number of consecutive days an amount was higher than 0 ("*days*" field).

| key | date | amount | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-01-22 | 10 | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-01-21 | 20 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-01-20 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-01-19 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-01-18 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-01-17 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-01-16 | 0 | 0 |

I have tried with some windows function using [this link](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-window-functions-rows-clause/). Did not add and reset to 1 if the previous amount is 0.

My code:

```
case when f.amount > 0 
     then SUM ( DATE_PART('day',  
                          date::text::timestamp - previou_bus_date::text::timestamp )  
              ) OVER (partition by f.key 
                      ORDER BY f.date  
                      ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
     else 0 
end as days
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: Thanks for reply ! I have 3 columns key , date and amount.  I would like  to generate 4th column days with above excepted value as above

Comment: Check Ahmed's answer, it's more efficient than mine. @Srb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, you could use the difference between two `row_number`s approach as the following:

```
select key, date, amount,
  sum(case when amount > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over 
  (partition by key, grp, case when amount > 0 then 1 else 0 end order by date) days
from
(
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by key order by date) -
    row_number() over (partition by key, case when amount > 0 then 1 else 0 end order by date) grp
  from table_name
) T
order by date desc
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JHDolvGS)

Answer (score 1):

This problem falls into the gaps-and-islands kind of problem, as long as you need to compute *consecutive* values of non-null amounts.

You can reliably solve this problem in 3 steps:

- flagging when there's a change of partition, by using 1 when current amount > 0 and previous amount = 0
- compute a running sum (with `SUM`) on flags generated at step 1, to create your partitioning, which to observe the number of consecutive values on
- compute a ranking (with `ROW_NUMBER`) to rank your non-null consecutive amounts in each partition generated at step 2

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           CASE WHEN amount > 0 
                 AND LAG(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY key_ ORDER BY date_) = 0
                THEN 1
           END AS change_part
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, 
           SUM(change_part) OVER(PARTITION BY key_ ORDER BY date_) AS parts
    FROM cte
)
SELECT key_, date_, amount,
       CASE WHEN amount > 0 
            THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY key_, parts ORDER BY date_)
            ELSE 0
       END AS days
FROM cte2
ORDER BY date_ DESC
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v3rtR9LGzLroNz16xu44mF/0).

**Note**: This is not the most performant solution, although I'm leaving it for reference to the next part (missing consecutive dates). @Ahmed's answer is more likely to work better in this case.

---

If your data should ever have holes in dates (some missing records, making the consecutiveness of amounts no-more valid), you should add a further condition in Step 1, where you create the flag for changing partition.

The partition should change:

- either if when current amount > 0 and previous amount = 0
- or if current date is greater than previous date + 1 day (consecutive dates are not consecutive in time)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           CASE WHEN (amount > 0 
                 AND LAG(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY key_ ORDER BY date_) = 0)
                  OR date_ > LAG(date_) OVER(PARTITION BY key_ ORDER BY date_)
                           + INTERVAL '1 day'
                THEN 1
           END AS change_part
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
...
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v3rtR9LGzLroNz16xu44mF/1).